# Sort all files in all folders by size

Tags: powershell

Using PowerShell, how do I sort all files in all folders by size?  Whenever I use the results of Get-ChildItem, even after it's saved to a variable and modified, it groups all files by directory.  Even then, the files aren't sorted in each directory.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *.bat -Path C:\git -Recurse
Sort-Object -InputObject $files -Property Length
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you're running into the default display mode of `System.IO.FileInfo`, which displays empty lines and the directory name whenever it changes.  It also takes forever to display because the `Mode` column is particularly poorly optimized.

Try something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *.bat -Path C:\git -Recurse |
    Sort-Object -Property Length |
    Select-Object -Property Length, Name |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't have the Reputation to comment yet (so I hope this is ok with stackoverflows etiquette), but Bacon Bits answer could be improved a bit by switching Select-Object and Sort-Object around:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *.bat -Path C:\git -Recurse | Select-Object -Property Length, Name | Sort-Object -Property Length | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

This will improve performance especially on large filesystems (about 50% if I use the above code on my C-drive)